# Populate a char array in C from another array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to copy content from one `char` array to another `char` array and below is my code,

```
char dest[100]; //destination array
char content[100]; //Which will be "11,22,33,44,55" - source array

//Split source array with comma delimiter
char *ch ;
ch  = strtok(content, ",");
while (ch != NULL) {
  printf("%s\n", ch); //prints each entry seperated by comma 
  ch = strtok(NULL, " ,");
  //Code to copy content to dest ?
}
```

i want to populate `dest` char array with below content,

**dest[0] = 11 dest[1] = 22 dest[2] = 33 dest[3] = 44 dest[4] = 55**

I have tried below with no luck,

```
memcpy(dest, ch, 1);
strcpy(dest,ch);
```

How can i do this?

**EDIT** : The source content is alpha-numerical (e.g) 11,2F,3A,BB,E1 is alos possible

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problems you have? How doesn't e.g. `strcpy` work? What is the result you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: Oh and you do the copying ***before*** the call to `strtok` in the loop?

Comment: `char dest[100];` --> `char dest[50][100];`.. `strcpy(dest[index++], ch);`

Comment: what is the max value of a token?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want. Please provide a [MCVE], e.g: `char content[100] = "65,66,67,68";` and `dest` array should then contain `"ABCD"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int  i = 0;
while (ch != NULL) {
  printf("%s\n", ch);
  dest[i++] = ch[0];
  dest[i++] = ch[1];
  ch = strtok(NULL, " ,");
}
```

assuming that `ch` has always two characters to copy.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you have to consider hex representations, which can be done by using strtol with base 16 (the OP gave input "11,2F,3A,BB,E1" as example):

```
int i = 0;
char *ch = strtok(content, ",");
while (ch != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", ch); //prints each entry seperated by comma 
    dest[i++] = (char)strtol(ch, NULL, 16);   // number will be 11, 22, 33 etc.
    ch  = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

Comment: Huh? In OP code, `dest[]` is an array of `char`, and `strtoul()` returns an `unsigned long`....

Comment: You still have the same problem. Why are you storing the `long` value returned by `strtol()` in a `char`? OP question is unclear, but so is this answer.

Comment: @David: Changed it. Results larger than 0xFF will be truncated. If OP wants long, then the array's declaration has to be changed.

Comment: We don't even know if OP intends `11,2F,3A,BB,E1` to be hex values. And why would you convert a hex string to a long value only to store it in a `char` anyway?

Comment: @David: Because it's a simple solution. I only assume that the OP wants to convert hex values, that's how I interpret the original question including the edit.

Answer (score 1):

instead of strtok, `content` could be parsed using sscanf. `%2hhX` will scan two hex characters and store the result in a `char`. `,` will scan any whitespace and a comma. `%n` will capture the number of characters processed by the scan to add to `ch` to parse the next field in `content`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main( void) {
    char dest[SIZE]; //destination array
    char content[SIZE] = "11,22,33,44 , 55,C,2F,3A,BB,E1";
    char *ch = content;
    int span = -1;
    int each = 0;

    while ( 1 == sscanf ( ch, "%2hhX ,%n", &dest[each], &span)) {
        printf ( "%hhX\n", dest[each]);
        if ( span == -1) {//failed to scan a comma
            break;
        }
        ch += span;//advance ch to next field in content
        span = -1;//reset span
        each++;
        if ( each >= SIZE) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```